# rpy2 access R named list items by name, low-level interface

Tags: rpy2

How do I access elements of a named list by name?

I have 3 functions, all of which return a `ListSexpVector` of class `htest`. One of them has 5 elements, `['method', 'parameter', 'statistic', 'p.value', 'data.name']`, others have a different number, and order. I am interested in extracting the `p.value`, `statistic` and `parameter` from this list. In R I can use `$`, like so:

```
p.value <- fit$p.value
statistic <- fit$statistic
param <- fit$parameter
```

The best equivalent I found in `rpy2` goes like:

```
p_val = fit[list(fit.do_slot('names')).index('p.value')]
stat  = fit[list(fit.do_slot('names')).index('statistic')]
param = fit[list(fit.do_slot('names')).index('parameter')]
```

Which is quite long-winded. Is there a better (shorter, sweeter, Pythonic) way?

---

There is the good-old-fashioned integer based indexing:

```
p_val = fit[3]
stat  = fit[2]
param = fit[1]
```

But it doesn't work when the positions are changed, and therefore is a serious limitation because I am fitting 3 different functions, and each return a different order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high-level interface is meant to provide a friendlier interface as the low-level interface is quite close to R's C-API. With it one can do:

```
p_val = fit.rx2('p.value')
```

or

```
p_val = fit[fit.names.index('p.value')]
```

If working with the low-level interface, you will essentially have to implement your own convenience wrapper to reproduce these functionalities. For example:

```
def dollar(obj, name):
    """R's "$"."""
    return obj[fit.do_slot('names').index(name)]
```

Comment: Oh, there is a `.rx2` accessor! I didn't know about it. Didn't find it in the docs. Thank you!

Comment: It is briefly mentioned here: http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html#extracting-r-style (although at the the moment there is no code example for it)